# Facebook Login doesn't work, what did I forget?

Tags: java, android, facebook

Ok,

I'm doing this for 4 straight hours. And the facebook Login still doesn't work. The session state is always OPENING. ALWAYS. onActivityResult NEVER gets called. The key in the developer console is correct, the starting class is correct, and this is my code

```
package XXXXX

import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import ua.org.zasadnyy.zvalidations.Field;
import ua.org.zasadnyy.zvalidations.Form;
import ua.org.zasadnyy.zvalidations.validations.HasMinimumLength;
import ua.org.zasadnyy.zvalidations.validations.IsEmail;
import ua.org.zasadnyy.zvalidations.validations.NotEmpty;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.content.pm.Signature;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;

public class SplashScreen extends FragmentActivity {

    public static String TAG = "SplashScreen";

    /**
     * LoginActivity
     */
    private static final int LOGIN          = 0;
    private static final int SIGNUP         = 1;
    private static final int SELECTUSERNAME = 2;
    private static final int FRAGMENT_COUNT = SELECTUSERNAME +1;
    private boolean isResumed               = false;
    private Fragment[] fragments            = new Fragment[FRAGMENT_COUNT];
    private MenuItem settings;
    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;
    private Session.StatusCallback callback = 
        new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, 
                SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    /** 
     * UI Elements
     */
    Button btn_signUp;
    Button btn_signUpSubmit;
    LoginButton btn_facebookAuth;
    //Edit Text
    EditText edittextEmail;
    EditText edittextPassword;

    //Form 
    Form signUpForm;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");
        uiHelper                        = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.splash);

        FragmentManager fm              = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragments[LOGIN]                = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.loginFragment);
        fragments[SIGNUP]               = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.signUpFragment);
        fragments[SELECTUSERNAME]       = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.selectUserNameFragment);


        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for(int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
        }
        transaction.commit();

        btn_signUp                      = ( Button ) findViewById(R.id.btn_signUpMail);
        btn_signUp.setOnClickListener( listener_btn_signUp );

        btn_signUpSubmit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signUpSubmit);
        btn_signUpSubmit.setOnClickListener(listener_btn_signUpSubmit);

        edittextEmail       = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_signUpMail);
        edittextPassword    = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.et_signUpPw);

        signUpForm          = new Form ( this );
        signUpForm.addField(Field.using(edittextEmail).validate(NotEmpty.build(this.getApplicationContext())).validate(IsEmail.build(this.getApplicationContext())));
        signUpForm.addField(Field.using(edittextPassword).validate(NotEmpty.build(this.getApplicationContext())).validate(HasMinimumLength.build(this.getApplicationContext(), 8)));

        btn_facebookAuth    = (LoginButton)findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        btn_facebookAuth.setReadPermissions(Arrays.asList("email"));
    }

    private OnClickListener listener_btn_signUp = new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            showFragment(SIGNUP, true);
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener listener_btn_signUpSubmit = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (signUpForm.isValid()) {
                Log.i("SignupFragment", "Form is valid");
//              User userModel = new User();
//              userModel.isFacebookConnected                   = "0";
//              userModel.userEmail                             = edittextEmail.getText().toString();
//              userModel.userPassword                          = edittextPassword.getText().toString();
//              SelectUserNameFragment selectUserNameFragment   = new SelectUserNameFragment();
//              SelectUserNameFragment.user                     = userModel;
//              getFragmentManager()
//              .beginTransaction()
//              .replace(android.R.id.content, selectUserNameFragment)
//              .addToBackStack("")
//              .commit();
            } else {
                Log.i("SignupFragment", "Form not valid");
            }
        }
    };

    private void showFragment(int fragmentIndex, boolean addToBackStack) {
        Log.i(TAG, "showFragment");
        FragmentManager fm              = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = fm.beginTransaction();
        for (int i = 0; i < fragments.length; i++) {
            if (i == fragmentIndex) {
                transaction.show(fragments[i]);
            } else {
                transaction.hide(fragments[i]);
            }
        }
        if (addToBackStack) {
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        }
        transaction.commit();
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onSessionStateChange");
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        int backStackSize = manager.getBackStackEntryCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < backStackSize; i++) {
            manager.popBackStack();
        }
        System.out.println ( state.name() );
        if (state.isOpened()) {
            Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                  @Override
                  public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
                    if (user != null) {
                        try {
                            User userModel              = new User();
                            userModel.facebookId        = user.getId();
                            Map<String, String> where   = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            where.put("where", "WHERE facebookId='" + user.getId() + "'" );
                            userModel.loadModelFrom(where);
                            if ( userModel.userData.isEmpty() ) {
                                userModel.isFacebookConnected   = "1";
                                userModel.userEmail             = user.asMap().get("email").toString();
                                SelectUserNameFragment.user                     = userModel;
                                showFragment(SELECTUSERNAME, true);
                            } else {
                                Intent intent = new Intent ( getApplicationContext(), DashboardActivity.class );
                                intent.putExtra("User", userModel);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                  }
            }).executeAsync();
//              showFragment(DASHBOARD, false);
        } else if (state.isClosed()) {
            showFragment(LOGIN, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();
        Log.i(TAG, "onResumeFragments");

        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null && session.isOpened()) {
            Intent intent = new Intent ( this, DashboardActivity.class );
            intent.putExtra("Session", session);
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            showFragment(LOGIN, false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.i(TAG, "onResume");

        uiHelper.onResume();
        isResumed = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        Log.i(TAG, "onPause");

        uiHelper.onPause();
        isResumed = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onActivityResult");
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.i(TAG, "onDestroy");

        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        Log.i(TAG, "onSaveInstanceState");

        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }
}
```

What did I forget?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is not allowed to have

`android:noHistory="true"` in your manifest. I removed it and now it works.